# Why does TypeScript allow duplicate component while implements?

Tags: angular, oop, typescript, inheritance, ecmascript-5

Why does TypeScript allow duplicate component while `implements`?

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class CreateVersionComponent implements OnInit, OnInit, OnInit { }// no error
export class CreateVersionComponent extends OnInit, OnInit, OnInit { }// getting error
```

*But it throwing **duplicate identifier error** while component extends*.

> So what is the reason for typescript accepting duplicate component while implements? which situation we need to use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand why the first code is not an issue, but the second is, you need to understand the difference between a class and an interface. An interface is a guarantee that its implementer will *at least* provide the interface members. It does not provide any actual functionality. A class however can contain implementation code; you can inherit from a class to reuse that code and change its behavior by adding new code or changing existing implementations.

That means `implements` and `extends` have different meanings. `implements` says: I can guarantee to every consumer of this class, that it will have at least the members of the interface. Since there is no actual implementation in the interface, it is no problem to make multiple of these guarantees, as long as the class implements all of them. You are right that it does not make any sense to add the same guarantee multiple times, but it does ot really hurt either. The creators of TypeScript could have forbidden to implement the interface multiple times. We can speculate why they didn't; my guess is that since TypeScript is based on JavaScript and JS is quite forgiving, they didn't want to forbid something that doesn't do any damage. Note that TS is a type layer on top of JS and all type information will be eventually dropped during compilation to JS. In this context, dropping multiple repetitive interface implementations does not really hurt, since the result will be exactly the same.

Other than `implements`, `extends` is a different story. While there are some languages that allow multiple inheritance (for example C++), multiple inheritance comes with a lot of difficult implementation details (such as the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) or calling base class constructors), so many languages do not support it with the idea that it causes more problems than it possibly solves. TypeScript does not allow multiple inheritance, which means you can not use `extends` with more than one base class on general principle. Unlike implementing an interface, inheriting a class has consequences on how the program works and the compiler will do much more than just stripping the type information. That's why it makes sense to raise an error there.

Comment: Thanks for your huge response! But I am lightly felt the information is not enough for my question : **what is the reason for typescript accepting duplicate component while implements? which situation we need to use it?**

Comment: @RameshRajendran: It's right in the answer: we can speculate why it's in there and it does not make sense to use it.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answers do a good job of explaining:

- Class vs. interface.
- multiple inheritance vs. implementing multiple interfaces.
- Interfaces being erased by compilation meaning the compiled code is no different with the redundant interfaces in the `implements` clause.

Yet some confusion remains.  To come at the question from another angle:

> which situation we need to use it?

You don't.  There is no situation that you need to declare redundant interfaces.  It reminds me of something like this:

`var v = v = v = 66`

*Yes*, it's fine as far as the compiler goes.  *No*, you don't ever need to do this.

> Why is it accepted?

It's easy to see why someone (especially someone with a Java background) might be confused by the lack of a warning.  After all, Eclipse has been warning me about this for years (Hello, `Serializable`!).

Having the same interface named multiple times in a single class definition is a little weird.  It might help to consider a redundant interface example that is more likely to actually happen:

```
interface StringProducer {
    getString: () => string;
}

class Parent implements StringProducer {
    getString =  function(): string {
        return 'x';
    }
}

class Child extends Parent implements StringProducer {
    getString = function() : string {
        return 'y';
    }
}

class GrandChild extends Child implements StringProducer {
    getString = function(): string {
        return 'z';
    }
}

console.log(new Parent().getString());
console.log(new Child().getString());
console.log(new GrandChild().getString());
```

You can (loosely) think of the `GrandChild` class like this:

`public class GrandChild implements StringProducer, StringProducer, StringProducer {`

since a class implements all its interfaces and those of its ancestors.

Should the compiler (or linter, perhaps) bark about this?  Should I **be forced to** remove the `implements` clause from `Child` and `GrandChild`?

I think this is largely a matter of preference.  For example, when I have `GrandChild` open in my IDE, I might want to see in that file all the interfaces the class implements.  On the other hand, I might feel like this is just noise, and want a warning.

The compiler certainly doesn't care, and doesn't need to.  But I can see why you might want a lint warning for this.  The question at the end of the day seems (to me) to be "Why isn't there a `tslint` rule for redundant interfaces?".  That's a reasonable question, that I can't answer.  [You could always write such a rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/) and share it with the rest of us.

Comment: You can (loosely) think of the GrandChild class like this:

`public class GrandChild implements StringProducer, StringProducer, StringProducer {}` interesting.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't allow multiple inheritance, much like Java, C# etc. So the second example won't work firstly because TSC thinks you're trying to extend more than one class, before it fails because it's the same class.

For the first case, I agree it should say something because it's probably a small mistake. On the other hand, it's not semantically wrong. When you're implementing the methods in the first `OnInit`, you're implementing it for the second and third as well, so you should be covered.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple.

Typescript does not allow **multiple inheritance**.

That means, one class cannot inherit from multiple classes. (This is for 'extends').

**Now lets come to 'implements'**.

In this case, we are talking about **Interfaces**. You can implement as many interfaces you need.

Keep in mind that implementing interfaces does not mean inheritance. It just means that you are implementing different **Models** on your class, to which your class definition has to adhere.

Hence, error on extends (Because of multiple inheritance, which is not allowed)
No error on implements (Because of multiple Interface implementation, which is allowed)